# Where do the implementations of the .aidl interfaces are done in android sourcecode?

Tags: android, android-source, aidl

I am working on the android gingerbread source code. I want to know where the method implementaions of these .aidl files are done so that i can add my own method and defination. I have searched everywhere through the framework folder of source code but not found. I espacially want the ITelephony.aidl Inteface methods implementation. Please tell me the location path taking framework as root OR some idea on how and where they are implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is in `packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/`.  Specifically,  `PhoneInterfaceManager.java` has these methods, but I believe it is just a layer on top of the various `Phone` class implementations.

Comment: hi, that was wonderful.. thank you very much.. :D
I am not looking in the packages folder and ofcource the name is completely different. Anyway thank you for your help..